# Algorithm for converting grammar to Chomsky normal form application

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am trying to apply the CNF algorithm to this grammar :

$S \to NT $

$N \to aNb | ε$

$T \to bTcc | ε$

Here is what I have done with all the steps,however at the end my answer is way different from the one in the book and I can't seem to find my mistake here is my soluton:

First I have removed the long rules and added the rules in the form $X \to m$ Then the grammar becomes :

$S \to NT$

$N \to A_{4}A_{1} | ε $

$A_{1} \to NA_{5} $

$T \to A_{5}A_{2} | ε $

$A_{2} \to TA_{3} $

$A_{3} \to A_{6}A_{6} $

$A_{4} \to a$

$A_{5} \to b$

$A_{6} \to c$

Now for eliminating the $ε$ rules I got :

$S \to NT | N | T$

$N \to A_{4}A_{1}  $

$A_{1} \to NA_{5} | A_{5}$

$T \to A_{5}A_{2}  $

$A_{2} \to TA_{3} | A_{3} $

$A_{3} \to A_{6}A_{6} $

$A_{4} \to a$

$A_{5} \to b$

$A_{6} \to c$

Here there are no cycles ,so we can just set the renaming rules and I got :

$S \to NT | A_{4}A_{1} | A_{5}A_{2}$

$N \to A_{4}A_{1}  $

$A_{1} \to NA_{5} | A_{4}A_{1}$

$T \to A_{5}A_{2}  $

$A_{2} \to TA_{3} | A_{6}A_{6} $

$A_{3} \to A_{6}A_{6} $

$A_{4} \to a$

$A_{5} \to b$

$A_{6} \to c$

Comment: Where you wrote $S -> NT,$ might you have meant $ S \to NT,$ or is that just my ignorance of this topic?

Comment: yeah for all the rules